# Percentage change day by day in Google DataStudio

Tags: percentage, looker-studio

I would like to generate an easy daily percentage change of `var` in Google Data Studio *day-by-day* as done below:

[image]

Basically, as shown in `C4`, -65.31% indicates that from day 2 to day 3 there was a decrement of 65.31% of `var` value and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created an [Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e948dd86-0a5d-4c18-8566-54c00044764b) to demonstrate the process below:

**1) dayPLUS1 (Calculated Field: Data Source-level)**
Create a metric that adds 1 to the Day field:

```
day + 1
```

For `YYYYMMDD` Date field calculations, use the formula below:

```
CAST(Date AS NUMBER )+1
```

**2) [Reaggregation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9429470) (Self Blend)**
Perform a self blend where the left Data Source includes values for the Day field and the respective metric, whilst the Data Source on the right includes the Day Plus 1 values:
**Data Source 1**

- ***Join Key***: `day`
- ***Metric***: `var`
  **Data Source 2**
- ***Join Key***: `dayPLUS1`
- ***Metric***: `varPLUS1` (rename the var metric)

**3) [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044) (Blended Data Source)**
Create a Table with the field to display the Daily Percentage Difference:

- ***Dimension***: `day`
- ***Sort***: `day` in Ascending order
- ***Metric 1***: `var`
- ***Metric 2*** (Calculated Field; Type: Number > Percent):

```
(SUM(var) / SUM(varPLUS1)) - 1
```